# Named Parameters vs Optional Parameters

Tags: c#

The optional parameters are nothing new in C# and I've known about that since the release of C# 5.0 but there is something I just came across. When I use Data Annotations for my MVC models such as the `Required` attribute I see this:

[image]

So I can do:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="Something"]
```

However when I create my own methods with optional parameters like:

```
void Test(String x = null, String y = null) {}
```

I can pass arguments in both these ways:

```
Test(x = "Test") OR Test(x: "Test")
```

this while in the `Required` attribute I always have to use the `=` and if I use the `:` it will cause error.
for example:

```
 Required(ErrorMessage:"Something") --> Compile time error
```

So what I see is that those Named Parameters are created differently than what I already knew about. And my question is How to make them for a method (How to create such Named Parameters like in the Required attribute).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An attribute has its own syntax. It uses the `name=value` form for named parameters.

For a normal method you can't use that form, you are stuck with the `name:value` form.

It would not be possible to use the `name=value` form for normal methods. The compiler would not be able to tell if you were trying to use a named parameter or if you were trying to assing a value to a variable and use the assignment as a parameter value.

Answer (score 2):

Despite this syntax looking like a method call:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="Something")]
```

An Attribute is a *class*, not a method. You aren't specifying an argument in the line above, you are initializing a property. See the example on the [Attribute base class documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to see what I mean.

The Attribute-specifying syntax is therefore similar to C#'s class initialization syntax:

```
new RequiredAttribute { ErrorMessage = "Something" };
```

There is currently no equivalent syntax in C# for specifying a named argument to a method.

Answer (score 0):

If you do something like:

```
string y; 
Test(y = "Test")
```

You can call a function with that syntax. But be careful... the `y = "Test"` is actually setting the variable `y`, and then passing that to the function! There is a side-effect there which is probably undesirable.  Also `"Test"` is getting passed into parameter `x` of the `Test` function, not `y` because it's going in as the first parameter.

In short, you should always avoid using this syntax when calling a function, because it doesn't do what you're expecting.